# Grails 3 does not have wrapper?

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-3.0

Does Grails 3.0.x no longer have the ability to create wrappers anymore?

The documentation doesn't seem to have the Grails wrapper section anymore.

Is there an alternative way which we can use the gradle wrapper to execute grails commands such as create-controller?

Comment: I have the same issue, now Grails 3 only creates a _Gradle wrapper_, but it can't execute many tasks like `create-controller`. Only the basic tasks like run the app or execute the test can be called with `gradlew`. I think that was a bad idea from Grails Development team remove this feature.

Comment: Let's follow this: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/8974

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Grails wrapper is back as of Grails 3.2.3:
http://docs.grails.org/3.2.x/guide/introduction.html#whatsNewGrailsWrapper

I have an app created with Grails 3.1.x, then upgraded to Grails 3.2.6, but the files such as 'grailsw' did not appear in my project root, and I'm not sure how to get them added via some command in the project.

When I create a new app using Grails 3.2.6, the new files are in the project root (grailsw, grailsw.bat, grails-wrapper.jar). I assume they can be copied over to an app like mine: a quick test of this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Grails 3.0.x no longer have the ability to create wrappers
>   anymore?

No.

> Is there an alternative way which we can use the gradle wrapper to
>   execute grails commands such as create-controller?

Not for commands like `create-controller`, no.

We may re-introduce grailsw.  File a feature request at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues if you would like to track that.

Comment: Appears this info is now outdated?

Comment: "Appears this info is now outdated?" - No, not really.  There are versions of Grails that have the wrapper and versions that don't.  This question was specifically about `3.0.x`, which does not have a Grails wrapper.